# Connecting Galaxy S2 ICS to Kies

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies, usb-connection-mode

I tried connecting my Samsung Galaxy SII(ICS) to Samsung Kies 2.0.2 through USB.

But whenever i connect the cable, Kies asks me to switch the phone to Kies Studio mode. But I could not find this mode in USB connection.

How do I connect my phone to Kies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting USB Debugging didn't resolve my issue. I upgraded Kies to the latest version. And it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Under `Settings → Applications → Development` **disable** *USB Debugging*. (In vanilla ICS this option is under `Settings → Developer options`)

   [image]
2. Plug your phone into your PC via USB **with Kies already running**.

(Found via [GalaxyForums.net](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/galaxy-s2-help/3565-how-enter-kies-studio-mode.html))